# Arrangement of lines in text file according to a list

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python, and I try to solve the following problem. I have a script that generates the arrangement of lines in text file and then move the lines according to the list. So, here is the problematic part of my script:

```
with open('POSCAR2', "r+") as f:
   line = f.readlines()
   N = line[0:4]
   Y = [1, 4, 2, 3]
   line = [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(Y,N), key=lambda x: x[0])]
   f.seek(0)
   f.writelines(line)
```

Initial arrangement was [1,2,3,4]

```
 0.0         0.0         0.0
 0.0         0.0         0.5
 0.0         0.5         0.0
 0.5         0.0         0.0
```

After running the script it became [1,3,4,2]

```
 0.0         0.0         0.0
 0.0         0.5         0.0
 0.5         0.0         0.0
 0.0         0.0         0.5
```

But I need [1,4,2,3].

So, how can I sort the lines according to a list?

Comment: How do you determine the final order of the lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y is permuting entry i to Y[i] so do Y = [1,3,4,2].

To get that from [1,4,2,3] you could do [Y[i-1] for i in Y], this will go between them.
Or adding it into your code.

```
line = [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(Y,N), key=lambda x: Y[x[0]-1])]
```